# php Str_replace Function

Tags: php, urlencode

I have the following 2 arrays that I am looking to replace variables from. However my problem is how to tell to not replace variables that are in `%XX` format. Right now `0` will get replaced with `%30`, and this will then again get replaced with `%%330` (replaced `3` with `%33`). Any help greatly appreciated.

```
$URL_Chars=array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','-','.','_','~',':','/','?','#','[',']','@','!','$','&','\'','(',')','*','+',',',';','=','%');

$URL_Encoded_Chars=array('%41','%42','%43','%44','%45','%46','%47','%48','%49','%4A','%4B','%4C','%4D','%4E','%4F','%50','%51','%52','%53','%54','%55','%56','%57','%58','%59','%5A','%61','%62','%63','%64','%65','%66','%67','%68','%69','%6A','%6B','%6C','%6D','%6E','%6F','%70','%71','%72','%73','%74','%75','%76','%77','%78','%79','%7A','%30','%31','%32','%33','%34','%35','%36','%37','%38','%39','%2D','%2E','%5F','%7E','%3A','%2F','%3F','%23','%5B','%5D','%40','%21','%24','%26','%27','%28','%29','%2A','%2B','%2C','%3B','%3D','%25');

$Hex_URL=str_replace($URL_Chars,$URL_Encoded_Chars,$Hex_URL);
```

Comment: Why are you reimplementing `urlencode`?

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that he wants to also encode all the letters/numbers as some kind of exercise. `urlencode` does not do this.

Answer (score 1):

You know you could do that in a cleaner fashion using [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace) using the `e` modifier:

```
echo preg_replace('/([A-Za-z0-9])/e', '"%".dechex(ord("\\1"))', 'Abc');
// outputs %41%62%63
```

If you want other characters too, just add them into the brackets `[]`, escaping them if necessary, of course.

Comment: First off, `eval` is evil.  Use `preg_replace_callback` instead.  Second, that doesn't solve the double encoding problem...

Comment: Don't even get me started with this "eval is evil" stuff. It is in some cases, but not this one. The above cannot execute arbitrary PHP code, the input is controlled and is always a single character.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the string:
Pick one chat at a time and if it equals '%' AND the following to chars are digits ignore rthose three, else replace the current char.

You can set your replacemnt rules with 1 assoziative array:

```
$replacements= array("A"=>"%41","B"=>"%42"....);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
function myUrlencode($url) {
    $encodedUrl = '';

    foreach (str_split($url) as $char) {
        $encodedUrl .= '%'.dechex(ord($char));
    }

    return $encodedUrl;
}
```

Comment: @Oliver A.: I think you're working in the wrong direction here. This is _encode_ not _decode_.